# Error executing sql query

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I try to execute the following query using java.sql.PreparedStatement:

```
SELECT  NVL (tb.ddate, '2002-10-15')
FROM tb
```

But get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: ¿¿¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿¿

What is wrong?

Comment: Wrong date format?
Month is usually in JAN, FAB or like that

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel: that is absolutely perfect date format. (October, 15th, 2002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date is not in expected format.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm

Or try:

```
SELECT  NVL (tb.ddate, to_date('2002-10-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') )
FROM tb
```